# is ValueError() an instance of the Exception class in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, instance, subclass

I'm a beginner in python.
I have to explain the difference between the following lines of code:

```
except ValueError as err:
    print(err,"in methodA is occured")
    raise ValueError("A Value Error")
```

and

```
except ValueError as err:
    print(err,"in methodA is occured")
    raise Exception("A Value Error")
```

I saw this "[Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)" in python documentation.

I know that in the second one we are passing the "Exception Class" to raise. but for the first one I'm not sure that the "ValueError" we are passing is an **instance of exception class** or is a **subclass of exception class**?

or am I getting this whole thing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: ValueError is a subclass of Exception. Therefore any instance of ValueError is an instance of Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, `help` function is often useful, just launch Python console and do `help(ValueError)` to get information that:

```
 Help on class ValueError in module builtins:

class ValueError(Exception)
 |  Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      ValueError
 |      Exception
 |      BaseException
 |      object
 |
...
```

in more verbose way: `ValueError` is `class`, `ValueError` is subclass of `Exception`, `Exception` is subclass of `BaseException`, `BaseException` is subclass of `object`.